# I cant install binance api to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, binance

I am currently trying to install the python-binance api to pycharm. I enter

```
python -m pip install python-binance
```

into the terminal and I get the error

`Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

I have also tried just
`pip install python-binance`

and I get the error

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install python-binance
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to get this working by using

```
py -m pip install python-binance
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tried `pip install python-binance` it give an error that pip is not recognized. That's one thing which can be solved with a virtual Environment.
Open your CLI and type `python3 -m venv name-of-env`, then `name-of-env/Scripts/activate`(for windows) for MacOs `./env/bin/activate`.
And if you now try `pip install python-binance` it shall work.

Comment: I am entering in python3 -m venv python-binance and it is still telling me the first error, python was not found